# Why do STL numeric algorithms use 'op' rather than 'op='?

Tags: c++, stl

Why do `std::numeric` algorithms seem to prefer ***op*** instead of ***op=***? For example, here is the implementation of `std::accumulate` in LLVM:

```
template <class _InputIterator, class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_Tp
accumulate(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Tp __init)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        __init = __init + *__first;
    return __init;
}
```

Would this not be potentially more efficient/less verbose/better if implemented using the `+=` operator?

Comment: I guess they wanted to support types that only has `+` but not `+=`, though I find it hard to recognize why one would not define `+` but not `+=` for a type.

Comment: It's a choice of a single interface: a + b sounds reasonable (having less requirements, it implies +=).

Comment: @DieterLücking While `a + b` has less requirements, `a = a + b` implies `a += b` is valid in any sane situation I can think of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### It is defined like this in the standard…

The standard is defined in terms of `+`, not `+=`:

> #### 26.7.2 Accumulate `[accumulate]`
>
> ```
> template <class InputIterator, class T>
>   T accumulate(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, T init);
> template <class InputIterator, class T, class BinaryOperation>
>   T accumulate(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, T init,
>                BinaryOperation binary_op);
> ```
>
> Effects: Computes its result by initializing the accumulator `acc` with the initial value `init` and then modifies it with `acc = acc + *i` or a`cc = binary_op(acc, *i)` for every iterator `i` in the range
>   `[first,last)` in order.

Same holds for other numerical algorithms.

### …and the standard is based on STL…

But that's the reason why they're *implemented* like this nowadays. However, to learn about the original reason, one needs to [go further down the rabbit hole](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html):

> #### Requirements on types
>
> For the first version, the one that takes two arguments:
>
> - `InputIterator` is a model of Input Iterator.
> - `T` is a model of Assignable.
> - If `x` is an object of type `T` and `y` is an object of `InputIterator`'s `value` type, then `x + y` is defined.
> - The return type of `x + y` is convertible to `T`.

### …and the STL has been created by…?

So, why is that? Lets ask Alexander Stepanov, the mind behind STL:

> [A] user has asked a [question] on StackOverflow two days ago concerning
>   the implementation and formulation of numerical algorithms like
>   `accumulate` or `inner_product`, which are defined in terms of `+`
>   instead of `+=` (section 26.7 in ISO C++11).
>
> I've tried to find some rationale behind the decision, but even the
>   version on SGI's page doesn't mention anything regarding this
>   particular choice of the operator.
>
> Was the choice of the operator (a = a + b instead of a += b) only
>   based on your personal preference, as some comments assume? Was a+b
>   the more natural way to write the operation back then? Or was it
>   simply a matter of symmetry between a = a +b and a = bin_op(a,b)?
>
> -- [Zeta]

Now, before you read his answer, remember that he started to write a generic library about ~30 years ago, and his and Meng Lee's initial document [The Standard Template Library](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/STL/DOC.PDF) will have its twenty years anniversary this October. Without further ado, I present his answer:

> I suspect that it was a matter of symmetry between a = a + b and a = bin_op(a,b), but I really do not remember. I should have written a rationale document stating all the reasoning between different design choices in STL, but I did not. Sorry.

<sup>(If Stepanov reads this by any chance: thanks again for your answer!)</sup>

I *personally* believe that the inspiration by Common Lisp's `reduce` has been another factor, but that's just speculation.

### What can one learn from this?

Sometimes, decision in a standard are based on personal preference and elegance. For example, if Stroustrup had written the STL, he would have "strongly prefer[ed] the use of a+=b as being a more direct expression of intent and typically faster than a=a+b". However, I have to admit that the symmetry between a = a+b and a=bin_op(a,b) has its own beauty.

That being said, this `a+=b` and `a=a+b` controversy will promote challenges:

> This issue will become very important when we define standard concepts, and I do not know how it will be resolved. [Stroustrup; also thanks to him for answering my question!]

That's all, I hope you've enjoyed the ride through a little bit of C++ history.

Comment: The `stl` does predate the standard, however.  If the pre-standard stl had `accumulate` and it was defined differently, then the standard (would probably) be different as well.  So the above answer is both definitive, and just kicking the can down the road.

Comment: *nod*.  I suspect the real answer is something along the lines "the idea that `+=` is a more fundamental operation than `+` is something that developed over the last 3 decades of C++ operator overloading, and was not nearly as obvious at the time `std::accumulate`'s precursor was written as it would be today.  So it was written using the "more simple" `x = x + y;` formulation, and the legacy remains with us today", but I am too lazy to do the research myself.  :)

Comment: @Yakk: Yeah, one feels like a [archaeologist](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/FAQ.html): "Is the STL Y2K compliant?" (FAQ entry). That being said, our short excavation of STL's tomb needs to be delayed till tomorrow :(.

Comment: @Yakk: Allright. I wrote an email. To the wrong person, but at least I wrote one. Stroustrup himself would have used `+=`, so I _guess_ it's most likely Stepanov's personal preference. I'll write him an email tomorrow.

Comment: So, what ***I*** personally learned from this: you can just ask the big ones some questions. However, I would never bother them with day-to-day questions – that's something for StackOverflow.

Comment: awesome!  I can only upvote this once, but I can upvote the question above as well.  It makes sense it was a seemingly random decision made years ago.  @Serthy made a great point below: if you have a type `T` with `int = int*T` and `int = T*int` overloaded, you can accumulate into an `int` without a `binop`.  There is, however, *no way to overload `int*=T`*.

Comment: @Yakk: Err, isn't it possible to simply define `const int& operator+=(int&, const UserType&)`? It compiles, but I don't have the standard at hand to check whether it's conform: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ef34fa28cfbcaf8

Comment: huh, I didn't know you could write a free `+=`.  Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 10):

It might be more efficient, and would clearly be less verbose.

The usual reason for doing things this way is to minimize the requirements on the underlying type. If you used `+=`, then the underlying type would have to support `+=`. For something like `int` that's trivial and already present, but for a class you define, it's entirely possible would define `+` and `=`, but not the compound `+=` (in which case, code that used `+=` would obviously fail).

Comment: Can you think of an example where you would support `+` and `=` but not `+=`? (I've even learned over the years that, under the hood, `+=` is a more fundamental operation and that you define `+` in terms of `+=`.)

Comment: @musiphil: I'm not sure of examples where it really makes *sense*, but I've seen a fair number that actually *did* support `+` and `=`, but not `+=`. I think in many (most?) cases it's a simple oversight, much like early code using iterators typically used `(*iterator).x` instead of `iterator->x`, because some (many?) early iterator implementations failed to provide working overloads of `->`.

Comment: It may be possible that for a given type `T`, an expression like `T+T` will not give a `T` value as a result... Such a type can have `+`and `=` both overloaded but not `+=`. Another possibility is like `*` for matrices, for which the product is a matrix but a necessary new matrix, it is not possible to define `*=` for a matrix...

Comment: Maybe its a type that you cannot extend further and the only way is to apply the global `operator` function?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès However, we need `Y = Y*T` to be valid, but `Y *= T` to not be valid.  In both of those cases, `Y = Y*T` does not hold, so not defining `Y*=T` makes sense.

Comment: @Yakk. I disagree. Y = Y*T is correct, it means that you want to store the result of Y*T into Y. But Y *= T means something more strong, changing Y, not replacing Y.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Please give a concrete example where `Y=Y*T` is correct but `Y*=T` makes no sense for concrete types `Y` and `T` (for either `*` or `+`).  (Naturally `Y` is a logically mutable type, or you couldn't assign to it).  Matrices are not one -- if `T` is a matrix type such that `Y*T` is type compatible with assigning to `Y`, `Y*=T` makes perfect sense.  An example of such a type might exist, but I cannot think of one off the top of my head.  Can you?

Comment: @Serthy then just write `X&+=Y` instead of `X = X+Y`?  You could even write the first in terms of the second.

Comment: @Yakk. Suppose you don't have operator overloading, would you naturally write a multiplyAndAssign function for matrices? Certainly not. Why using operator overloading would change something? This is exactly why, overwriting * and = don't provide you an automatic overloading of *=.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the main reason is that you could use standard functional object `std::plus` and get the same result as with `operator +` the same way as using `operator <` and standard functional object `std::less` in sorting algorithms like `std::sort`.

Comment: An argument for `std::plus_assign` if I ever heard one

Comment: @Yakk There is no such function in C++ Standard at list neither in C++ 2003 nor in C++ 2011. As an idea then it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of reasons for using + instead of +=.

A. Because it is the correct way.  [Accumulate is fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), a functor (a function that maps functions to functions) that operates on +, not +=.  Why + instead of +=?  Because += is not a mathematical function.

B. It is more efficient (on modern compilers, on all primitive types and well-designed objects).  += might be faster for compilers 30 years ago, but + is faster now, unless what you are accumulating is a monstrous object with too much OO.  Object lifetime analysis is easier done on const objects rather than references.

C. It is clearer.  This reason is really not substantially different from (A).  + is clearer than +=.  Clarity trumps verbosity.

Comment: Re (B): tried `std::accumulate` on a vector of `std::string`? Maybe compiler 30 years _from now_ will be able to optimize that into code that is as efficient as a version using `+=`.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz Three problems: A. Why are you using strings in performance sensitive parts of your code? B. What's the accumulator? Are you sure in your case += is faster than +? C. If your accumulator is so hard to construct repeatedly that you have to resort to mutable states, then you could just do `for ( item : collection ) acc += item;` instead of reaching for functional stuff.

Comment: A) I didn't say this is performance-critical code. But even so, quadratic behaviour *will* be noticable. B) std::string (so accumulate concatenates all strings in the vector). And yes. (Big-)Oh yes. C) I'm a disciple of Alex Stepanov and Sean Parent. I don't write Raw Loops...

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz As I understand it, 'raw loop' means manual incrementation of loop counter, which is not what I wrote in the previous comment.  If however, you really want to use the functional style while still have mutable state, you can always pass in a lambda that closes over an external variable and achieve the same thing.

Comment: (Raw Loops) No, I use Sean Parent's definition: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning (Mutable State) I think you misunderstand. This is not Haskell. `std::accumulate` doesn't recurse, it iterates, so it needs mutable state: the accumulator. The question here is _how_ it mutates it: `acc = acc + next` or `acc += next`. Since `+` creates a tmp. `std::string` on each loop iteration, this is _O(N²)_ overall. For `+=`, the complexity is _O(N)_. The result should be identical, for regular additive types.

Comment: And what does a Haskell compiler do other than transforming high level functional constructed into low level implementation details?  We are still running von neumann machines and there will be mutable state if you care to look down far enough.  The whole point is to move away from explicitly representing that mutable state whenever you can.

Comment: If the authors had actually wanted mutable state, they should have let you pass the initial value by reference instead of by value.  Besides, this is defined in <numeric>, which implies that the operands are supposed to be lightweight values, not ugly reference types such as `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

The truth, I guess, is reuse. The rest of the STL is using binary *operators* while `+=` is an *action*. So there's `plus`, `multiplies`, etc, but no `add_action` (say). Operators and actions are completely symmetric, but if you implement more than 90 algorithms, at some point you'll probably have to stop adding new concepts and Ship It.

Alex has said that he never intended for his STL to be the end of all STL development, esp. since the standardized version contains only a fraction of what he originally proposed. This is an obvious extension.